# What's the reasoning behind downvoting duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I always wonder, why downvote dupes? I know what the downvote stands for/means. But for some reason I don't feel like it applies to (some)dupes.

***This question does not show any research effort***

Sometimes I fail to find the information I want/need after several searches in SO and end up posting a duplicate, some if not most of the information is easily found by mods/highrep/veteran users. It doesn't necessarily mean I didn't search well enough, or that I didn't put enough effort does it? It's information that can be found by them cause they've seen it before or they favorited the question. Most of the times it's all about the wording of the question what makes some users unable to find the information they want/need, and that can be a bit difficult since everyone's chain of thought is different.

***It is unclear***

If it's unclear, then how come we found out it's a dupe?

***or not useful***

Dupes are useful(or so I think, from my little experience/time in this network) cause old questions tend to be forgotten, having new questions that point to these old ones is a way to keep the information accessible for anyone, regardless of their time in the network.

Maybe I see things in a different/wrong way, and that's why I'm posting this question, hoping that if I'm wrong I can get corrected.

P.S. I know everyone is entitled to do as they please with their vote privileges, and I'm not promoting the upvote of duplicates either. I'm simply trying to understand.

Comment: In the end, it does come down to "Everyone can vote as they please." But in most cases, it seems to be a case of "no research effort" (i.e. The downvoter pastes the question title into Google and the very first result is a perfect dupe target) or "not useful" (i.e. the new question doesn't introduce anything new in terms of, well, terms to help redirect searchers to the original. (Often times, this will likely actually be tied in with "no research" if you think about it.)) Really, unless people comment on their downvotes, no one but the downvoter knows on any given downvote.

Comment: **Some** duplicates are useful signposts. Many more are simply because the OP was too lazy/incompetent to find the existing question(s) before dumping their own on the community. The *age* of the question is often irrelevant, new questions are only useful if they use different *language* that may help others (who actually bother to search) to find the canonical information. *"It doesn't necessarily mean I didn't searched well enough, or that I didn't put enough effort does it?"* - not *necessarily*, no, but it doesn't guarantee that you did, either!

Comment: Are you suggesting duplicates never be downvoted?

Comment: No I am not, just trying to understand site's guidelines/procedures/reasoning @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not seeing where you're getting that exactly. This reads more like the OP doesn't feel the downvote reasons fit and is trying to see why others feel that they do, in my mind.

Comment: That's exactly what I was aiming for @Kendra

Comment: @Kendra If they aren't suggesting that, then every post should simply be judged on its own, not because it's a duplicate. It's as simple as that. Some questions do not show research effort, regardless of whether they've been asked before. Some questions are unclear, regardless of whether they've been asked before. And some questions are not useful, regardless of whether they've been asked before.

Comment: It's cause sometimes I spend a good amount of time looking for what I want and I can't find it, then the original question mine was marked duped as has a title I never thought of using or never came up to mind, etc @jonrsharpe I think searches are too based on titles, and that can be sometimes misleading

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton you asked in the general case, and that's my opinion. If there are *specific* questions you think have been mishandled, then by all means talk about those.

Comment: I never said anything about mishandling, but thanks for the suggestion @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some duplicates are upvoted, because they are useful, but those are *rare*.

Why are they rare?

Because people for the most part consistently ask the same few basic questions, in the same crappy way, using mostly the same words:

Which means even if the question is clear, it fails

- in research (typing a few of the words they used into google would have found one of the myriad dupes),
- in presentation (Sturgeon's law), and
- it is completely useless (It cannot be repurposed as a useful sign-post, as nobody will find it who wouldn't also have found one of the others).

If you should post one of those rare ones, more power to you, and thank you for erecting a good sign-post. Hopefully, all will point to a good dupe-target which is comprehensively answered and well-curated, because attention is focused there.
As a corollary, any dupe which isn't dupe-closed for the master is a net-loss because it leads to scattering the useful answers every which way. If you find an answer adding to those already in the master, flag for a mod to merge them.

Comment: Thank you, I was clearly thinking in a different/wrong context/way

Comment: +1 It's also often the same question which can answer the problem simply with different code/variable names/etc.